# How to include variable in Regular expression pattern

Tags: regex, vba

I am working on a vba macro which uses regular expression to search for a string pattern in another string.

Regex pattern includes a string (APR24 in code below) which varies. I need to know how to include a variable in the pattern.Could any one please help.

My code is as below

```
Public Function Regexsrch(ByVal str2bsrchd As String, ByVal str2srch As String) As Boolean
Dim Regex As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches, s
Regex.Pattern = "(\.|\s)APR24(,|\s|\()"
Regex.IgnoreCase = True
    If Regex.Test(str2bsrchd) Then
         Regexsrch = True
Else
        Regexsrch = False
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify whatever pattern you want in `str2srch` and then assign that to `Regex.Pattern`

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Regexsrch("APR24ddd", "APR24")  '<~~ Returns True
    Debug.Print Regexsrch("APR277ddd", "APR24") '<~~ Returns False
End Sub

Public Function Regexsrch(ByVal str2bsrchd As String, ByVal str2srch As String) As Boolean
    Dim Regex As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim matches, s

    Regex.Pattern = str2srch
    Regex.IgnoreCase = True

    If Regex.Test(str2bsrchd) Then
         Regexsrch = True
    Else
        Regexsrch = False
    End If
End Function
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Even if it is dynamic you can always pass the pattern as

`Debug.Print Regexsrch("APR24ddd", "(\.|\s)" & VARIABLE & "(,|\s|\()")`.

This gives you the flexibility of using whatever pattern you want to pass to the function and you are not limited to one pattern...

Comment: See followup in the post above

Comment: @Downvoter: I don't mind the downvote but at least have the decency to leave a comment as to why you feel a downvote is required? Or is the too much to ask for?

Answer (score 5):

So str2srch is "APR24" or some variation? If that is the case you just use concatenation to build up your pattern string.

```
Public Function Regexsrch(ByVal str2bsrchd As String, ByVal str2srch As String) As Boolean
Dim Regex As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches, s
Regex.Pattern = "(\.|\s)" + str2srch + "(,|\s|\()"
Regex.IgnoreCase = True
    If Regex.Test(str2bsrchd) Then
         Regexsrch = True
Else
        Regexsrch = False
End If
End Function
```

Comment: The regex can be improved by using character classes, eg, `Regex.Pattern = "[.\s]" + str2srch + "[,\s(]"`